# How do I add arbitrary javascript files from GitHub in jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript, github, jsfiddle

I know jsFiddle used to support arbitrary javascript files from GitHub, but not anymore. May be GitHub has changed its mime type of raw files. what are the alternatives when the required js files is not in any cdn (may be its less popular js repo).

Comment: That citations doesn't make your question better, [this is actually exactly the type of question you should *not* ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Better ask "*How can i include javascript libraries from arbitrary github repositories without hosting them myself when fiddling around*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an old question I see, but still I've found the answer:

1. Get the Raw URL of the Github file you need to include. e.g. you will have https://raw.github.com/k4r573n/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder/master/Control.OSMGeocoder.css
2. Remove the dot (**.**) between "raw" and "github" and **use that resulting url in the jsfiddle**. e.g. you will end up having https://rawgithub.com/k4r573n/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder/master/Control.OSMGeocoder.css that works just perfect in jsfiddle.

Why this works? because of the rawgithub.com service that serves the content with the correct MIME type.

And obviously, credits to http://www.geekdave.com/2013/06/19/linking-raw-github-files-from-jsfiddle/ where I actually found the answer I needed.

Cheers!

Comment: @Tengiz..despite I was able to add a file from github with the method described above...this does not have any effect in the my fiddle script.Τhis is the file I added https://github.com/patrickkunka/easydropdown/tree/master/src and this is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlehunt/3Ucg7/.                       It is a plugin for styling dropdown menus-if you click anywhere in the calendar(as shown in the fiddle) a dropdown menu appears inside a dialog box.This ought to be styled by the plugin but there is no change whatsoever.

Comment: well....I found a solution to it.I had to use http://rawgit.com/. I still cannot understand though what is the point of removing the dot between "raw" and "github".I just used the link that the above service gave me...I did nothing else.